# wear leveling count low on smart check

Tags: ssd, smart

My wear levelling count went really down.

How much should I be concerned, how long will it last?

I saw the recommendations to always back up and saw some topics where people said it will still work for some time after would reach 0 for a long time I had under 10 GB free and many times I even got under 100mb space but changed that now, maybe that was an issue?

My main concern would be how long my SSD will last.

smart test results:

[image: smart test results:]

Answer (score 0):

> my main concern would be how much will it last my ssd.

The indicator of how long an SSD will last, for a very good quality SSD) is TBW on your machine against the design limit.

My ThinkPad SSD is good for 600 TBW and now 4.5 years in and running 3 virtual machines non stop I am still under 40 TBW. My SSD will outlive the computer.

TBW is the best measurement for a good quality, working SSD.

You can always run the manufacturer's drive test app to see if there are any SSD errors.

Also you can (and should) run the TRIM command occasionally as this reduces overall wear level by marking used disk space for reuse. That is the best thing for wear levelling. Windows is good at doing this by itself.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but still have some unclarities, if don't mind answering. where do i see the tbw you are talking about in my report? are the total host writes from the upper right or the total lbas written from down? also, could you please send a link to that manufacture drive test?

Comment: You can (and should) run the TRIM command occasionally as this reduces overall wear level by marking used disk space for reuse. That is the best thing for wear levelling. Windows is good at doing this by itself.  For Link - I use Samsung Drives and Samsung Magician. Look for Samsung Magician.

Comment: thank you for the answers

Comment: The wear levelling measurement in your added chart indicates the need to enable and run the schedule for the TRIM command. That should serve to reduce wear levelling over time.

Comment: and how do i do that? sorry, i am a bit of noob in this matter. it's like an command in the cmd?

Comment: Open Admin Tools on Windows 10 (or Windows Tools on Windows 11) and select Optimize Drives. Make sure TRIM is set to run weekly. I checked both my SSD machines and TRIM is running weekly

Answer (score 0):

If there's any important data on the disk, **take a backup *now***. Also take care to take fresh backups regularly.

Filling an SSD to the brim makes it age faster. With lots of free space, the controller's wear leveling can distribute writes more evenly and spread the aging process over more cells (assuming it's TRIMmed properly). With very little free space, a small pool of cells is constantly written to, making them age faster. (That isn't the case with all SSD models but unless you know for sure you have to prepare for that.)

Wear Leveling Count is set by the controller to show how much 'life' is left in the flash cells. If that indication is correct, you could lose data any time now. Depending on how accurate that indication is, the disk could last another day, another month or another year. Nobody could say for sure (short of an expert with a semiconductor lab).

You should replace the SSD as soon as possible. You should also consider a larger model that isn't filled completely all the time.

Comment: thank you for the answer. for backup i should have an external drive and what software would you reccomand for it?

Comment: @dariusV16 What you are asking in this comment is simply a new question. Next steps are yours. There is no one software that is best for a case like this: Get a new drive — internal or external; whatever you can use — and copy data off of the drying drive immediately.

Comment: Normally in a Windows system, filling to the brim will shut Windows down.  Allow yourself at least 25% free space.

Comment: Also if you need to back up old documents - use a High Quality USB Drive. Plan for a larger main drive soon.